# Tor Browser Screen Resolution

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor browser is showing as giving a large number of bits of identifying information and creating a more unique browsinng session. Is there a way to change screen resolution and color depth to match the most common (1920x1080)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a common screen size?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-use-a-common-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite true and you may not want to do that. The reason Tor randomly changes your browser resolution is actually to make you harder to find. The resolution in one session isn't going to be the same as in a previous one. In this, Tor goes for a more spoofing like technique rather than a blending in technique. In this context which one would be more effective in protecting you I'm not quite sure of, however if the Tor developers chose this feature over default 1920x1080, then I'm sure it was the better option.